# DocuSign API : Error creating envelope, "Notary not enabled. Notary Tab is not support for this account

Tags: docusignapi

I'm not including any Notary tabs in my envelope creation. Not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm in the developer account.

EDIT: After further testing, it appears the PhoneNumberTabs are causing this error. When I remove those tabs from the Envelope package, the request is successful.

Including JSON of my Envelope. Let me know if you need more to help. I'm using the C# REST API and we have an existing integration using much of the same codebase, the only difference is the kind of document's we are sending. We normally use Server Templates, this particular process is modifying and sending a word document as Base64 (removed) for signing.

```
{
"compositeTemplates": [],
"customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [{
            "name": "QuoteId",
            "value": "Some Val"
        }
    ]
},
"documents": [{
        "documentBase64" : "base64string",
        "documentId": "1",
        "fileExtension": "docx",
        "name": "Client Services Agreement"
    }
],
"emailBlurb": "Hello! Please sign this stuff!",
"emailSubject": "Please find attached paperwork",
"recipients": {
    "signers": [{
            "email": "***",
            "name": "Jordan ***",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "roleName": "Signer1",
            "tabs": {
                "dateTabs": [{
                        "anchorString": "<<dob1>>",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabId": "dob1"
                    }
                ],
                "emailTabs": [{
                        "anchorString": "<<email1>>"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<email2>>"
                    }
                ],
                "phoneNumberTabs": [{
                        "anchorString": "<<homephone>>"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<cellphone>>"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<addphone>>"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<faxnumber>>"
                    }
                ],
                "signHereTabs": [{
                        "anchorString": "<<signhere1>>",
                        "recipientId": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "ssnTabs": [{
                        "anchorString": "<<ssn1>>",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabId": "ssn1"
                    }
                ],
                "textTabs": [{
                        "anchorString": "<<fullname1>>",
                        "originalValue": "Jordan ****",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabId": "fullname1"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<address>>",
                        "shared": "true",
                        "tabId": "address"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<apt>>",
                        "shared": "true",
                        "tabId": "apt"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<city>>",
                        "shared": "true",
                        "tabId": "city"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<state>>",
                        "shared": "true",
                        "tabId": "state"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<zip>>",
                        "shared": "true",
                        "tabId": "zip"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "<<county>>",
                        "shared": "true",
                        "tabId": "county"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "bestcontacttime",
                        "shared": "true"
                    }, {
                        "anchorString": "bestcontactway",
                        "shared": "true"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
"status": "sent"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Update** the `phoneNumberTabs` are a feature of Notary and may not be allowed without using the Notary feature. The error message could be improved to mention the specific tab you're trying to use.

As for Notary, you should be aware that the Notary API is in a closed beta at the moment, and is only available for DocuSign Notary customers. If you are interested in Notary, we'd encourage you to fill out this form https://www.docusign.com/contact-sales-notary.

Comment: I’m not using any references to Notary functions. I’ve validated that the signer doesn’t have any NotaryTabs (in C# the NotaryTabs list is null).

Comment: Please add the code you are using to the question, I can't really help much with the one line you wrote...

Comment: Updated post with JSON representation of the envelope object.

Comment: You are sending this JSON from C# code? exactly like that? and you get the Notary error? this is very weird. Are you not using the C# SDK (Nuget package)?

Comment: I'm using the C# SDK. Just figured it'd be easier to show you the JSON representation of the Envelope I'm requesting. That JSON is the output of calling JsonConvert on the 'env' variable below in my code (we've got plenty of C# DocuSign code already live and in production, but never seen this):
EnvelopesApi envApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient);
           EnvelopeSummary summary = envApi.CreateEnvelope(AccountID, env);

Comment: Update... I started removing Tabs until it worked. Turns out that adding the PhoneNumberTabs is causing that failure. I assume this is a bug, how should it be reported?

Comment: yes, that is odd, I'll try to ask around about this and update if I find anything

Comment: Jordan, got a quick answer so far which suggests this is desired behavior but confusing error message. I'll try to get more thorough answer, but thanks for brining this to our attention!

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to be able to use the PhoneNumber tabs so any help on the actual underlying cause of the exception would be helpful. Is it possible there is a requirement/setting I'm missing when creating those Tab types?

Comment: If you need a phone number - use a text tab with a mask/regular expression validation that makes it a phone number as you desire